# jquery animate() is not working

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $("input").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

```css
pre{
    background-color: #0099cc;
}

pre > b{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

pre > input{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <pre><b>Hi , this is phani and you are seeing my portfolio.<b><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="works" value="works"></input></pre>
</header>
<script src="../js/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

While I am applying the `hide()` in JQuery then it is working, but when I am using animation it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `top/right/bottom/left` property to work, you must use on that element `position: relative/absolute/fixed`.

So, because you're not using `position` property, you can then animate the `margins` (in your case `margin-left`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on('click', function() {
    $("input").animate({
      marginLeft: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}
pre > b {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
pre > input {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <pre><b>Hi , this is phani and you are seeing my portfolio.<b><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="works" value="works"></input></pre>
</header>
```

Also, your HTML **is not valid**. Use [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to check your markup.

Comment: yes, I didn't because you also didn't. [Here's an valid fiddle which animates the `left` property](https://jsfiddle.net/y3su1h0j/).

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question but today i find that except hide and its toggle nothing is working

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").hover(function(){
        $(this).text("hi this is phani");
    });
 $("input").click(function(){
        $("input").hide();
  });
});  ` this is my code but notworking

Comment: my html is `<header>
<div id="head"></br><h1>Hi , this is phani and you are seeing my portfolio.<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="works" value="works"></input><h1></div>
</header>
<section>
<img class="img-responsive" src="phani.jpg" width="50%" height="75%" alt="phani"></img>
<article>`

Answer (score 0):

Add position absolute in input box and try:

```
<pre>
<b>Hi , this is phani and you are seeing my portfolio.<b>
<input type="button" style="position:absolute;" class="btn btn-success" name="works" value="works"/>
</pre>
```